# jQuery Issue in IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7

I'm using the Horinja (http://www.davidmassiani.com/horinaja/index.php) jQuery Library for a site I am working on: 
[My Site](http://www.lceonline.co.uk)

But when loading in IE7, It doesnt seem to function, Can anyone help me out, Or point me in the direction of a fix?

Works fine in FireFox, IE8 & IE9.

Screenshot of the issue : http://img828.imageshack.us/i/ie7issue.jpg/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may want to elaborate a bit more... what does it do? what is it supposed to do but not do? etc...

Comment: Basically "It doesnt function" - Meaning the images load into the page, But the animation does not kick in.

Comment: What is supposed not to work? I got the same behaviour (which seem correct) with IE7 and Chrome. Edit was working 1minute ago and now is a mess in IE.

Comment: Interesting. Basically the images load into the page. But actually appear behind the "Featured Products" The animation does'nt kick in and the images are static. http://img828.imageshack.us/i/ie7issue.jpg/ - Link to issue

Comment: When I view in IE8 in compatibility mode it appears a bit messed up also (featured brands are below).

Comment: Have you trued running this in IE8's IE7 mode with Debugging (press F12) and checking for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this. The jQuery had 1 too many commas in it. Which prevented it from functoning in IE7.